# Running a script on every page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I am new to the forum, first question!
I am quite a beginner so it might be very basic...

I am trying to implement a code that will make iframes responsive

```
(function($) {

$.fn.responsiveVideo = function() {
    // Add CSS to head
    $( 'head' ).append( '<style type="text/css">.responsive-video-wrapper{width:100%;position:relative;padding:0}.responsive-video-wrapper iframe,.responsive-video-wrapper object,.responsive-video-wrapper embed{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%}</style>' );

    // Gather all videos
    var el = $(this),
        all_videos = el.find( 'iframe[src*="player.vimeo.com"], iframe[src*="youtube.com"], iframe[src*="dailymotion.com"],iframe[src*="kickstarter.com"][src*="video.html"], object, embed' );

    // Cycle through each video and add wrapper div with appropriate aspect ratio
    all_videos.each( function() {
        var video = $(this)
            aspect_ratio = video.attr( 'height' ) / video.attr( 'width' );

        video
            .removeAttr( 'height' )
            .removeAttr( 'width' );

        if ( ! video.parents( 'object' ).length )
            video.wrap( '<div class="responsive-video-wrapper" style="padding-top: ' + ( aspect_ratio * 100 ) + '%" />' );
    } );
};
} )(jQuery);
```

To activate it I am calling it with this code:

```
$(window).ready(function() {    
 $( 'body' ).responsiveVideo();   
    });
```

My problem is that it works only on the first load of a page or when refreshing a page. When I navigate to a page that contains an iframe it doesn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: keep the `responsiveVideo()` function out of `(function($) {`.

Comment: It would help if you explained what it is supposed to do and what happens when "it doesn't work"

Comment: You're sure it's not working correctly with **new** iframes that haven't loaded yet, as there's no onload handler in that code?

Comment: And only the document has a ready handler, the window does not.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
$(window).load(function() {    
 $( 'body' ).responsiveVideo();   
});
```

instead of

```
 $(window).ready(function() {
```

Hope tihs helps you :)